# Apache Spark: worker can't connect to master but can ping and ssh from worker to master

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to setup an 8-node cluster on 8 RHEL 7.3 x86 machines using Spark 2.0.1. start-master.sh goes through fine:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp /usr/local/bin/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/usr/local/bin/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host lambda.foo.net --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 22181@lambda.foo.net
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/12/08 04:26:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://lambda.foo.net:7077
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.0.1
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://19.341.11.212:8080
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
16/12/08 04:26:46 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

But when I try to bring up the workers, using start-slaves.sh, what I see in the log of the workers is:

```
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp /usr/local/bin/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/usr/local/bin/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://lambda.foo.net:7077
========================================
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 14649@hawk040os4.foo.net
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
16/12/08 04:30:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 35858.
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 15.242.22.179:35858 with 24 cores, 1510.2 GB RAM
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.0.1
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Worker: Spark home: /usr/local/bin/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://15.242.22.179:8081
16/12/08 04:30:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master lambda.foo.net:7077...
16/12/08 04:30:00 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master lambda.foo.net:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:216)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to lambda.foo.net/19.341.11.212:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: lambda.foo.net/19.341.11.212:7077
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
16/12/08 04:30:12 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
16/12/08 04:30:12 INFO Worker: Connecting to master lambda.foo.net:7077...
16/12/08 04:30:12 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master lambda.foo.net:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
```

So it says "No route to host". But I could successfully ping the master from the worker node, as well as ssh from the worker to the master node.

Why does spark say "No route to host"?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: the firewall was blocking the packets.